# Using subgit to migrate non-standard layout subversion repository with no branches, tags and trunk

Tags: git, svn, subgit

I have been using subgit to convert my subversion repository to git. Unfortunately, I have a sub-project in one of my branches which is not in standard layout. The non-standard sub-project is not included in the conversion.

The content of the sub-project is

```
/my-subproject
   file1
   dir1
     subdir1-file1
   file2
```

Is there a way to specify it in the mapping in subgit.conf? Below is the mapping in subgit.conf.

Eg.

```
[git "my-subproject"]
translationRoot = my-subprojcet
repository = /var/git/my-subproject.git
pathEncoding=UTF-8

trunk = trunk:refs/heads/master
branches = branches/*:refs/heads/*
shelves = shelves/*:refs/shelves/*
tags = tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

Comment: Could you schematically show your repository structure from the repository root (including trunk/branches/tags/shelves of the main repository)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As found in [subgit project mapping](http://subgit.com/book/#projects-mapping) the configuration should be

```
[git "my-subproject"]
repository = /var/git/my-subproject.git

translationRoot = /

trunk = /my-subproject:refs/heads/master
branches = branches/project/*:refs/heads/*
shelves = shelves/project/*:refs/shelves/*
tags = tags/project/*:refs/tags/*
```

I hope this would be useful.

Answer (score 3):

see`subgit help configure` ,with '--layout directory'

subgit configure --layout directory ....

'directory' : treat URL as a branch and only translate that branch

Answer (score 3):

I was able to import a project from SVN to gitHUB with no trunk or branches by doing the following.

```
checkout svn directory
subgit import --non-interactive --svn-url svn://svn/MyProject
subgit configure --layout directory svn://svn/MyProject repos.git
*Manually edit authors.txt to map accounts 
-- note that [svn] trunk is: trunk = :refs/heads/master

subgit install repos.git
cd repos.git/

git remote add github https://github.com/linkrd/NewMyProject
git push github --all --follow-tags
```

All 6000+ pf my previous commits were there.